# How to play .m3u8 file on flutter web using video_player plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-packages, hls.js

Just tried  video_player plugin  with flutter web and .m3u8  file format, but it's not working  at all .
Can someone help me if it works in any case or just MP4 is supported in video_player plugin for  flutter web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter Web, I found some libraries that support playing m3u8 files like video_player_web_hls but it's not providing any controls like Play/Pause, Fast Forwarding, etc.

[video_player_web_hls](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web_hls)

Answer (score -1):

also  you should check thse two plugins
add to your pubspeck.yaml

```
video_player: ^2.7.2
video_player_web: ^2.1.1
```

get these from official pub dev
https://pub.dev/packages/video_player
and
https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web
respectivly

Comment: Angelos, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)